# Setting width of page

Tags: pdftex, r, knitr

I would like to control the width of the document, i was able to set the margins more the the left (https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/www/latex/guide/node30.html)
But that just moved the text to the left aswell. I would like for the plot and the text to fill up more of the space on the page. preferably to the red arrow indicated in the output.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{article} 
\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{simplemargins}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-1.in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{2in}

\title{TEST}
\author{me}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
    pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
some text 
<<echo=FALSE,results='hide',warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,fig.keep='all',fig.show = "asis",warning=FALSE,fig.width=15,fig.height=15>>=
df<-data.frame(x=rnorm(100))
plot(df$x)
@

\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Thanks for reading, and i'm sorry if this has been answered somewhere completely obvious.

Update

It seems that just adding `\usepackage{geometry}` did something, it gave it a little bit.

[image: moved from deleted post]

I am however still not able to control the size of the document by any variable.

reading the knitr doc I found that

```
out.width="1\\paperwidth"
out.width='1\\textwidth'
out.width='1\\linewidth'
```

this didn't do anything either.

including `options(width=60)` or `(width=80)` inside the R chuck did nothing.

When i used `\addtolength{\textwidth}{6in}` and `\setrightmargin{-.1in}`

I was able to move the page number, not the main text

If there is anyone who has written in knitr who can give a specific suggestion as to the code to use i would be very happy.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please read the documentation of the package `geometry` which has been written for such things.

Comment: using the Documentation https://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAAahUKEwjJ9r3a3LDHAhUkw3IKHU59ALk&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftexdoc.net%2Ftexmf-dist%2Fdoc%2Flatex%2Fgeometry%2Fgeometry.pdf&ei=4iTSVcn9F6SGywPO-oHICw&usg=AFQjCNG02yhPsHt99ZTbKgfXZUxqLfuS9A&sig2=EmnXvhzYCytze2oVs4Kx7A&cad=rja

i found

     \usepackage[text={7in,10in},centering]{geometry}

which i inserted after \addtolength{\textwidth}{2in}
which made the pdflatex.exe fail. 

I then tried 

    \usepackage[total={6.5in,8.75in},top=1.2in, left=0.9in, includefoot]     {geometry}

Which also failed

Comment: The problem may be due to incompatibility between geometry and either Sweave or simplemargins (neither of which are supported by MikTex).

Comment: So you can't control the size of the page with MikTex ?

i just need a solution that allows me to determin the size of where the text/figures are. That must be possible

Comment: I cannot compile your code without error when I comment out `simplemargins` (which I don't know where to find). Do not use both `geometry` and manual adjustments to the layout. `geometry` is the better option. You need `\hypersetup` in the preamble. You also need to layout the page in the preamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know where to find `simplemargins` so I've commented that out. I still get compilation errors. However, here are some hints:

- `\hypersetup` needs to be in the preamble: right now, it complains that you are setting things up too late and it is ignoring e.g. `colorlinks` (if it still works, that is just because that's default);
- page layout needs to be done in the preamble.

Don't mix `geometry` and manual setting of dimensions. `geometry` is preferable.

For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{simplemargins}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{% needs to be in the preamble
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
    pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\title{TEST}
\author{me}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
some text
<<echo=FALSE,results='hide',warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,fig.keep='all',fig.show = "asis",warning=FALSE,fig.width=15,fig.height=15>>=
df<-data.frame(x=rnorm(100))
plot(df$x)
@

\end{document}
```

If I ignore the compilation error (never wise), I get this:

[image: initial state]

The lines are the result of the `showframe` option. Obviously, this is just for help in figuring out the settings you want - you wouldn't use this option except for debugging and configuration.

Altering the example slightly for testing purposes and to avoid the errors:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{simplemargins}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{% needs to be in the preamble
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
    pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{TEST}
\author{me}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\kant[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image: Kant: initial state]

Altering the options passed to `geometry` makes it easy to alter the page dimensions. Here's a slightly extreme example using 85% of the page width and height:

```
\usepackage[showframe,scale=.85]{geometry}
```

[image: Kant: slightly extreme]

Use `hscale` to alter the horizontal scaling only, or `vscale` to modify just the vertical. Or specify the margins or textwidth you want.

`texdoc geometry` will give you a comprehensive list of the available options. The `verbose` option will give you console output with a summary of the results of the calculations.

Obviously, I have no idea whether this is compatible with `simplemargins`. That sounds rather like a competitor package, just from the name, in which case combining it with `geometry` would be a Very Bad Idea Indeed.

Comment: @user2673238 You're welcome!